# How do I import my own python files?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, spyder

In a file named `BinarySearch.py` I have the following:

```
class SearchResult:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.was_found = False
        self.index = 0
    def __str__(self): 
        s = "SearchResult"
        s = s + "  was found:  "
        s = s + str(self.was_found) + "index:  " + str(self.index)
        return s
```

In another file, let's say it is named `file2.py` I have:

```
import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
import sys
sys.path.append(cwd)

import BinarySearch
```

However, when I try to run `file2.py`, I get the following error message:

```
NameError: name 'SearchResult' is not defined
```

It looks like the `import BinarySearch` did not actually import `BinarySearch`

I am using the Spyder IDE. Both files (`BinarySearch.py` and `file2.py`) are in the same directory. Also, I went to Tool > PYTHONPATH manager and added the directory to the path. I also tried restarting spyder to see if that was what was required for the path change to go into effect. It still doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

The line in `file2.py` which threw the error was the following:

```
sr = SearchResult()
```

Originally I assumed that the statement `import BinarySearch` would have the same behavior as if I copied the entire contents of BinarySearch.py and pasted it right where the `import` statement was inside file2.py. I see now that's not how `import` works.

Answer (score 5):

The current directory is already in the path without you having to explicitly put it there in any way (through the IDE or through sys.path)

In your second piece of code you're missing the last line which I asume is giving you the error, and most likely is something like

```
print(SearchResult())
```

It should be

```
print(BinarySearch.SearchResult())
```

Or you could change your import to

```
from BinarySearch import SearchResult
```

And then you can just do

```
print(SearchResult())
```

Comment: `from BinarySearch import SearchResult` is not sufficient. There are other things inside the file BinarySearch.py, things besides`SearchResult`, which I also need.

Comment: In that case either use `import BinarySearch` and refer to each thing with the module name: `BinarySearch.SearchResult`, `BinarySearch.SomethingElse`, ... or use `from BinarySearch import SearchResult, SomethingElse`. Another option is to use `from BinarySearch import *` and that will let you use everything inside BinarySearch, but this is [discouraged](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/doanddont.html#from-module-import)

Answer (score 0):

One solution seems to be to change the import statement from

```
import BinarySearch
```

to:

```
from BinarySearch import *
```

The star/asterisk essentially means "import all," which imports everything from the file `BinarySearch.py`, including the `SearchResult` class.

The regular plain simple import also imports everything, but forces you to access things through a namespace. Everything from the file `BinarySearch.py` is now inside the namespace `BinarySearch`. We could leave the original `import` statement alone, but anytime we use something in `file2.py` which comes from `BinarySearch` we would have to add a prefix. We would have code that looks like this:

```
# inside file named file2.py
sr = BinarySearch.SearchResult()
```

If we get tired of writing `BinarySearch.` before things all the time, we can create an alias for the namespace, like so:

```
import BinarySearch as bs
```

Then, inside `file2.py`, the statement `sr = bs.SearchResult()` will work just fine.